# if $L \in NP$ then its mapping reducible to HALT?

Tags: np

This is true because every language in $NP$ is decidable and therefore HALTS but how do I formally show this?

Comment: What do you mean by *mapping reducible*? If you mean a many-one computable reduction, then since the language is in NP, the reduction itself can determine whether the instance is a Yes or a No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what type of reduction you're talking about. But if you mean a "many-one reduction with no time constraints" (a Turing machine that transforms instances of problem $L$ to instances of problem `HALT` such that the answers remain the same), then yes.

The algorithm goes something like this:

- Take an input $x$
- Use brute force to decide whether $x \in L$ (in potentially exponential but still finite time)
- If the answer is "yes", let $T$ be a Turing machine that always accepts
- If the answer is "no", let $T$ be a Turing machine that always diverges
- Return $\langle T \rangle$

Now, when $\langle T \rangle$ is passed to a `HALT` oracle, the oracle will accept if $x \in L$, and reject if $x \not \in L$.